# Automated install of remote Linux host OS

Tags: centos, system-installation

A server with no operating system will be plugged into an Ethernet network using an Ethernet cable.  **Can another machine on the network run an automated script that will remotely install CentOS 7 as the host OS on the new server?  If so, how do I set this up?**

Currently, I have to manually install the new CentOS 7 host using a DVD or USB copy of the CentOS 7 `iso` file.  This includes a GUI-based installation process that I would like to replace with a fully-automated process.

I know that some hardware manufacturer's have administration tools that accomplish this on hardware that they manufacture themselves, but I am looking for something that is agnostic to hardware-vendor.

Comment: If the system is set up correctly to do what is normally called a `network boot`, then yes. The first keyword to look for is pxeboot. You boot a live image, which as part of its startup reads a config file and  it then installs the OS based on the values in the file.

Comment: Yup, a few nuts to crack here. First is the PXE boot.  Then PXE booting appropriate install media.  Then using install media that has an appropriate automated install process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The existing machine that the new machine will be connecting to will need to have a server which can provide PXE boot services.

Your best source of information for CentOS would be the RHEL official documentation.

PREPARING FOR A NETWORK INSTALLATION
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/chap-installation-server-setup.html

You can also look into Kickstart Files
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/chap-kickstart-installations.html